# Heading counters, even if there is no h1

Tags: css, css-selectors

I found this CSS code:

```css
body { counter-reset: h1counter; }
h1 { counter-reset: h2counter; }
h2 { counter-reset: h3counter; }
h3 { counter-reset: h4counter; }
h4 { counter-reset: h5counter; }
h5 { counter-reset: h6counter; }
h6 {}

h1:before {
    counter-increment: h1counter;
    content: counter(h1counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
}

h2:before {
    counter-increment: h2counter;
    content: counter(h1counter) "." counter(h2counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
}

h3:before {
    counter-increment: h3counter;
    content: counter(h1counter) "." counter(h2counter) "." counter(h3counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
}

h4:before {
    counter-increment: h4counter;
    content: counter(h1counter) "." counter(h2counter) "." counter(h3counter) "." counter(h4counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
}

h5:before {
    counter-increment: h5counter;
    content: counter(h1counter) "." counter(h2counter) "." counter(h3counter) "." counter(h4counter) "." counter(h5counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
}

h6:before {
    counter-increment: h6counter;
    content: counter(h1counter) "." counter(h2counter) "." counter(h3counter) "." counter(h4counter) "." counter(h5counter) "." counter(h6counter) ".\0000a0\0000a0";
}
```

It works fine if there is an h1 element:

```html
  <h1>asdf</h1>
  <p>ppp</p>
  <h2>h2</h2>
  <h3>h3</h3>
  <h2>h2</h2>
  <h3>h3</h3>
```

[image]

But when there is no h1....

```html
  <h2>h2</h2>
  <h3>h3</h3>
  <h2>h2</h2>
  <h3>h3</h3>
```

... nothing works anymore:

[image]

The expected result would be either...

```
1. h2
1.1. h3
2. h2
2.1. h3
```

... or:

```
1.1. h2
1.1.1. h3
1.2. h2
1.2.1. h3
```

---

How can I fix this to work **if there is an h1** and **also if there is none**?

Why I want this? Because I'm using a note taking app that accepts CSS to style the notes, but the h1 is kind of optional.

I tried working with `:has()` to check whether there is an `h1`, but failed, because my CSS skills aren't that good.

Is there maybe a possibility in CSS to define "If there is an h1 anywhere, do this.. Otherwise, do that"?

Comment: Change `body` so that all of the counters are reset there, not just `h1counter`. Leave the rest of it the way it is.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. Only disadvantage: There is a prefix "0." in front of everything.

Comment: That's seems like it would be expected given that there's no "first" h1.

Comment: I specified in the question above the best possible result.

Comment: You'd need javascript. CSS barely has the ability to act on ordering at all and your ask is outside that capability.